sorting python dataframe by values in a column based on a list
I have a pandas dataframe which I am trying to sort on the basis of values in a column, but the sorting is not alphabetical. The sorting is based on a "sorter" list (i.e. a list which gives the order in which values should be sorted).
However, I am getting error when I do this.
executable code below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'JDate':["2022-01-31","2022-12-05","2023-11-10","2023-12-03","2024-01-16","2024-01-06","2011-01-04"],
        # 'Month':[1,12,11,12,1,1],
        'Code':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy','George Lucas'],
        'Unit Price':[np.nan,200,None,56,75,65,60],
        'Quantity':[1500, 140000, 1400000, 455, 648, 759,1000],
        'Amount':[100, 10000, 100000, 5, 48, 59,449],
        'Invoice':['soccer','basketball','baseball','football','baseball','ice hockey','football'],
        'energy':[100.,100,100,54,98,3,45],
        'Category':['alpha','bravo','kappa','alpha','bravo','bravo','kappa']
})

df["JDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["JDate"])

df["JYearMonth"] =  df['JDate'].dt.to_period('M')


index_to_use = ['Category','Code','Invoice','Unit Price']
values_to_use = ['Amount']
columns_to_use = ['JYearMonth']


df2 = df.pivot_table(index=index_to_use,
                            values=values_to_use,
                            columns=columns_to_use)

df4 = df2['Amount'].reset_index()

# setting up the sorter
sorter=['football','ice hockey','basketball','baseball']


#trying the categorical method
df4['Invoice'] = df['Invoice'].astype('Category').cat.set_categories(sorter)

df4.sort_values(['Invoice'],inplace=True)



df3 = df2.xs('alpha',level='Category')
df3 = df3.reset_index() #this prevents merging of rows


writer= pd.ExcelWriter(
        "t2test11.xlsx",
        engine='xlsxwriter'
    )


df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2",index=True)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2test",index=True)
df4.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2testFixHeader",index=True)
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2filter",index=True)

writer.close()



a few issues:

you can directly convert using pd.Categorical instead of .astype;
this would be a custom order, then you sort, so use ordered=True;
you tried to use df["Invoice"] instead of df4["Invoice"]`

try:
df4["Invoice"] = pd.Categorical(df4["Invoice"], 
                                categories=sorter, 
                                ordered=True)

df4.sort_values(["Invoice"], inplace=True)

result:
In [45]: df4["Invoice"].head()                              
Out[45]: 
0      football
4      football
3    ice hockey
1    basketball
2      baseball
Name: Invoice, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['football' < 'ice hockey' < 'basketball' < 'baseball']


If we look at the dtypes reference in the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes
It lists the Categorical data type string alias as 'category'.
Changing:
df4['Invoice'] = df['Invoice'].astype('Category').cat.set_categories(sorter)
To:
df4['Invoice'] = df['Invoice'].astype('category').cat.set_categories(sorter)
Resolves the issue

Create a dictionary from the list, create an order column using the dict, sort.
I want to sort by col1:
import pandas as pd

data = {"col1":["A", "B", "C", "D"], "col2":[1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#   col1  col2
# 0    A     1
# 1    B     2
# 2    C     3
# 3    D     4

order = ["B", "C", "D", "A"]
order = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(order)}
#{'B': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'A': 3}

df["order"] = df.col1.map(order)
#   col1  col2  order
# 0    A     1      3
# 1    B     2      0
# 2    C     3      1
# 3    D     4      2

df = df.sort_values(by="order")
del(df["order"])
#   col1  col2
# 1    B     2
# 2    C     3
# 3    D     4
# 0    A     1

